# Doctrine + CodeIgniter: after generate entities with namespace, "cannot redeclare class" on schema create

Tags: codeigniter, namespaces, doctrine, entities

I'm trying to generate both entities and the database schema with Doctrine under CodeIgniter 2.0, using annotations. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.
 I've setup base classes which have only the classname and properties defined, and then annotated. I'm trying to use the generate-entities command to have it create the get/set methods.

```
<?php  
namespace Entities;

include('ContentItem.php');


/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="blobs")
 */
class Blob extends ContentItem {    

/**
 * @var ContentItemId
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ContentItem")
 * @JoinColumn(name="contentitem_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $contentitem;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
 */
protected $content;

/**
 * @Column(name="date_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
protected $date_created;

/**
 * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
protected $date_updated;
}
```

This file is located in a folder named 'models'. If I run the command 'orm:generate-entities models', then it creates new classes inside of '/models/Entities' folder. This only happens because of the 'namespace Entities' declaration. If I run 'orm:schema-tool:create' to try and create my database schema, I get: "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Entities\Blob in /Users/rw3iss/Sites/ci/application/models/Entities/Blob.php on line 11".
This is happening because the generated 'models/Entities' classes inherit the namespace from the files they're generated from in the parent 'models' folder, hence the dual class conflict.

Now if I remove the namespace declaration from the parent files, and call generate entities, passing 'models/Entities' as the destination, I get the same file layout. Except then, when trying to use the models in my code:

```
$blob = new Entities\Blob;
```

this throws the same error, obviously because there are still two classes with the same name, without a namespace.

I have declared the Entities class loader like this:

```
$entityClassLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', APPPATH.'models');
```

So my question is:

Is there anyway to generate these entity classes from a basic class (which has my annotations declared for the class and properties), preserving namespaces, so that I can still instantiate them using 'new Entities\Blob'? If there was even a way to tell the generated classes to use a different namespace from the file's they're generated from, that would be fine. I'd like to setup basic properties, and have the 'generate entities' command create my get/set methods for me. It seems that whenever I use namespaces, it will auto-create the classes inside of the namespace subfolders, and then I get the 'cannot redeclare class' error.

Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong...

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:** Solution:

I may have gotten it working by putting the Entities folder side by side with my models folder. If I change the Entities ClassLoader to point to just 'APPPATH', and then instantiate my Entities using 'new Entities\Blob', then that works. 
It seems like there is no way to put the Entities folder as a subfolder within the models folder without it complaining in some way. If anyone know of a way to do this, I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: Editing the library files is never really a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem. That's because you specify a subfolder in the command.
Just type : `"orm:generate-entities ."` (without quotes)

`"."` is meaning actual folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working with entities and models in two different subfolders. Here is how i processed :

my files structure :

```
+ framework (root folder)
  index.php
  + entities (model folder)
     Formation.php
     + repositories (repositories folder)
        FormationRepository.php
  + controllers ( controllers folder)
     HomeController.php
```

in index.php :

```
require 'vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$entitiesLoader = new ClassLoader('entities', __DIR__);
$entitiesLoader->setFileExtension('.php'); // not necessary, i think that .php is set by default
$entitiesLoader->register();

// registering entities repositories classloader
$repositoriesLoader = new ClassLoader('entities\repositories', __DIR__);
$repositoriesLoader->setFileExtension('.php');
$repositoriesLoader->register();
```

here is an entity : (Formation.php)

```
// Formation.php
<?php
namespace entities;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="entities\repositories\FormationRepository")
 * @Table(name="formations")
 */
class Formation
{
....
```

here is how i use it : (in HomeController.php)

```
// in HomeController.php
<?php
// if i need it directly :
use entities\Formation;
$formation = new Formation();

// if i want to use it with its repository (and Doctrine)
$formation = $this->getApp()->getDbConnection()->getRepository('entities\Formation')->findOneById(1);
```

pay attention to "getRepository('entities\Formation')". My mistake was to not specifying the namespace "entities\" before the name of the entity.